# Properly testing an API wrapper for Recurly

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec, isolation

I'm thinking about the way that I can test this class, its interface only exposes two methods, add_property and remove_property which just wrap the Recurly API.

```
class SubscriptionManager

  def initialize(account_code)
    @account_code = account_code
  end

  def add_property
    subscription.update_attributes subscription_add_ons: [{ add_on_code: 'property', quantity: property_count + 1 }]
  end

  def remove_property
    subscription.update_attributes subscription_add_ons: [{ add_on_code: 'property', quantity: property_count - 1 }]
  end

  private

  def property_count
    subscription.add_ons.first[:quantity]
  end

  def subscription
     @subscription ||= Recurly::Subscription.find(@account_code)
  end
end
```

Here is the outlines of the test that I am trying to write, but my goal here is not to hit the API since the Recurly gem provides a nice wrapper with its own set of tests.  However, I'm starting think I can only do this by hitting the API.  Anyone have any ideas?

```
describe SubscriptionManager do
  subject  { SubscriptionManager.new('1') }

  before do
    subscription = mock 'Subscription'
    Recurly::Subscription.stub(:find).with('1').and_return subscription
  end

  describe 'add_property' do
    it 'increases the quantity of the property add on' do

    end
  end

  describe 'remove_property' do

    it 'decreases the quanity of the property add on' do

    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [VCR gem](https://github.com/myronmarston/vcr) - it allows API testing without hitting the API once set up.

Comment: THis is not what I meant, I want to avoid hitting the model all together.  The API is well tested, I don't need to hit it, I can accurately stub it and understand what the responses should be.

Comment: @TheDelChop - Unfortunately, stubbing the responses and testing your code that way is what you will have to do in testing an API wrapper